# Писать ли с заглавной первое слово в названии театра?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная, названия

«...государственного академического музыкального театра Крыма».

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если эти слова относятся к официальному названию театра, то даже если начальные слова из него опущены, первое слово из оставшихся пишется с заглавной буквы (если только неполное название не совпадёт с другим и тем самым не обезличится).

Comment: а как быть с государственным унитарным предприятием....«рога и копыта» к примеру?

Comment: я не думаю, что в данном случае нужно писать с заглавной....

Comment: А здесь ещё "хуже": бывает, что эти страшные слова входят в официальную аббревиатуру ФГУП (Федеральное...) и все четыре пишутся с большой буквы. http://shkola-televideniya.ru/tv/nii/ Надеюсь, в вашем случае нет какого-нибудь ГАМТ?

Comment: ГУП РК "Крымгазсети" у меня....ведь таких ГУПов много, только названия в кавычках разное, и все равно первое слово писать с большой буквы?

Comment: Первое слово и здесь с большой (Государственный), если входит в название (в примере со ФГУП - тоже только первое, по ссылке выше неверно самоназвались). http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5